# ローカル上では通るのに、CIではエラーになる：VCR::Errors::UnhandledHTTPRequestError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, circleci

Ruby on Railsで開発をしています。

ローカルでは問題なくテストも通りましたが、CIを通した途端に`VCR::Errors::UnhandledHTTPRequestError`のエラーが発生しました。↓

```
Failures:
AppNotifications::RoutineNotifier.notify when post data exists is expected not to raise Exception
     Failure/Error: expect{ described_class.notify(type) }.to_not raise_error

     Minitest::Assertion:
       expected no Exception, got #<VCR::Errors::UnhandledHTTPRequestError: 

       =========================================================...n/ignore-request
       ================================================================================

       > with backtrace:
```

試したこととしては、
cassettesを削除するために、該当のVCRコードを書き換えてテストを再実行し、再度VCRコードを元の状態に直しました。

（ちなみにspec/rails_helper.rb上にある`VCR.configure do |c|`のブロック内に `c.allow_http_connections_when_no_cassette = true`を挿入してカセットを削除しました。）
しかし、これを実行したところ先ほどとは別のエラーが下記のように複数発生しました。

```
Failure/Error: data = SilentFetcher.fetch(remote_picture_url)

SilentFetcher::ExpectedError:
  Errno::ECONNREFUSED: Failed to open TCP connection to lvh.me:3000 (Connection refused - connect(2) for "127.0.0.1" port 3000) by http://lvh.me:3000/******/test.png
------------------
--- Caused by: ---
Errno::ECONNREFUSED:
  Connection refused - connect(2) for "127.0.0.1" port 3000
```

このコミットではビューファイルとコントローラーの条件分岐の書き方少しを触った程度ですが、直接は関係ないと思われます。
思い当たるとすれば、直前に`git reset --hard`を行なったことくらいで、それまではCI上でも通っていました。

同時進行で行なっているブランチでも同じエラーが出てきてしまい、解決方法がわからず困っています。
どなたかご教授いただければ幸いです。よろしくお願いします。